# Why does changing maxResults cause the total number of results to change in Google API / Gmail API?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

Why does changing the `maxResults` parameter cause the `resultSizeEstimate` to drastically change when calling `gmail.users.messages.list()`?

The [Google API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) docs lists `resultSizeEstimate` as:  *Estimated *total number* of results.*

... which means this final result set should not change just by altering the number of items returned per page.

**Example A: `maxResults: 1` ... `resultSizeEstimate: 8`**

```json
{
  "config": {
    "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=before%3A2021%2F1%2F9&maxResults=1",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
      "User-Agent": "google-api-nodejs-client/0.7.2 (gzip)",
      "Authorization": "Bearer [snip]",
      "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    "params": {
      "q": "before:2021/1/9",
      "maxResults": 1
    },
    "responseType": "json"
  },
  "data": {
    "messages": [ ... ],
    "nextPageToken": "14911817971227869758",
    "resultSizeEstimate": 8
  },
  "headers": {
    "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"",
    "cache-control": "private",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-encoding": "gzip",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "date": "Sun, 09 Jan 2022 12:59:48 GMT",
    "server": "ESF",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "vary": "Origin, X-Origin, Referer",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "x-xss-protection": "0"
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

**Example B: `maxResults: 2` ... `resultSizeEstimate: 12`**

```json
{
  "config": {
    "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=before%3A2021%2F1%2F9&maxResults=2",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
      "User-Agent": "google-api-nodejs-client/0.7.2 (gzip)",
      "Authorization": "Bearer [snip]",
      "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    "params": {
      "q": "before:2021/1/9",
      "maxResults": 2
    },
    "responseType": "json"
  },
  "data": {
    "messages": [ ... ],
    "nextPageToken": "16903415066875011466",
    "resultSizeEstimate": 12
  },
  "headers": {
    "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"",
    "cache-control": "private",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-encoding": "gzip",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "date": "Sun, 09 Jan 2022 13:10:48 GMT",
    "server": "ESF",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "vary": "Origin, X-Origin, Referer",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "x-xss-protection": "0"
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

**Example C: `maxResults: (not set)` ... `resultSizeEstimate: 412`**

```json
{
  "config": {
    "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=before%3A2021%2F1%2F9",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
      "User-Agent": "google-api-nodejs-client/0.7.2 (gzip)",
      "Authorization": "Bearer [snip]",
      "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    "params": {
      "q": "before:2021/1/9"
    },
    "responseType": "json"
  },
  "data": {
    "messages": [ ... ],
    "nextPageToken": "16942818266524948378",
    "resultSizeEstimate": 412
  },
  "headers": {
    "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"",
    "cache-control": "private",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-encoding": "gzip",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "date": "Sun, 09 Jan 2022 13:09:05 GMT",
    "server": "ESF",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "vary": "Origin, X-Origin, Referer",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "x-xss-protection": "0"
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was previously reported in Issue Tracker and was considered to be intended behavior by Google, since `resultSizeEstimate` is not expected to be exact; it's an "estimate":

> the reason why **resultSizeEstimate** shows differents values is due to its estimation. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list#response-body) **resultSizeEstimate** is just an estimated total number of results but not the exact number of results.

#### Reference:

- [users.messages.list method returns different amount of messages when using “maxResults” parameter](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184173911#comment4)